# How do I gsub ' with empty?

Tags: r, gsub

For example for a string like this

`NANYANG-GIRLS'-HIGH-SCHOOL`

how  do I use gsub to replace ' to empty and make it

`NANYANG-GIRLS-HIGH-SCHOOL`

when I do it in R, it shows error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of the following two approaches:

```r
sec_name <- gsub('\'', '', sec_name, fixed=TRUE)
sec_name <- gsub("'", "", sec_name, fixed=TRUE)
```

This first approach is a correct version of what you were doing.  Here, we use single quotes for the strings, but we escape the single quote to make it a literal single quote.